# Release Pipeline Very Slow

Tags: performance, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline that usually runs in about 3 minutes per environment, but my last two releases have been incredibly slow tonight, including one that has now been running for an hour!

Is anyone else experiencing slowness? Of course, Azure status reports green across the board.

UPDATE: same thing is happening tonight, except now not only are my releases slow (25 minutes instead of 3) but one of my swap slots failed.

UPDATE2: regarding demands to clarify my question, it was basically an shout out to see if anyone else was experiencing slow performance since the Azure status showed green across the board. Same thing tonight... not sure what other details are required.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!



Please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a release pipeline that usually runs in about 3 minutes per
>   environment, but my last two releases have been incredibly slow
>   tonight

For this issue ,there is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which affected these services, and it has been resolved . I think your problem has gone away. If you want to know more information, please click [here](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/170971640). Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I think that outage must have been the issue. It lasted maybe 90 minutes or so but was frustrating since I was trying to deploy.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you , would you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),so it could help other community members who get the same issues.Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

@steve: Couple of things you should consider in this regard;

1. In case of using private agents to build/release your pipeline, compute is in your hand, and you can amend the configuration for the machine you are consuming,
2. Make sure to validate the limitations specific to your devops account https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops

I hope this would be helpful to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the Azure public agents